# Is this possible, scaling the width, height & angle of a diagram via html5 and blender?

Tags: game-engine

Hey there I have a upcoming project where the client would like to have a diagram of a river where it's width, height and angle can be adjusted by the end user on a html5 website.

Here's an example of what I mean changing the angle, ie it makes the river have a steeper incline, thus the rate of water flows faster.

Would I use Blender's game engine for this?

[image: river]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blender's game engine outputs _.exe_ files. You might be interested in such technologies such as WebGL or use an interactive model viewing site such as http://p3d.in/.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the Blender game engine in a browser. Some options you have are:

- Display pre-rendered image in the browser, you would have to render animation sequences for the water for each angle. (Bad idea)
- Import Blender model to three.js using this [addon](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).

  - [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAwORb8MUG0)
- Use a Javascript 3D graphics framework like [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) with WEBGL shaders

Related
[image]
- [WebGL Water](http://madebyevan.com/webgl-water/)

- [water-simulation-in-three-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828004/water-simulation-in-three-js)
- [Water](http://jsfiddle.net/gero3/UyGD8/9/)

Comment: Thanks for that stacker. So by pre-rendering each image, would that mean all combinations ie 

• seq1 = change in width
• seq2 = change in height
• seq3 = change in angle
• seq4 = change in width and height
• seq5 = change in width and angle
• seq6 = change in height and angle

etc?

I also saw this game done with Blender too http://www.inkfood.com/spacedebris

Comment: @pancreasboy That looks to be using threejs, Blender has an exporter of sorts for that I believe.